# How to set a proxy when creating an instance of phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, slimerjs

I'm trying to create an instance of phantomjs using a proxy...

```
// require
var phantom = require('webpage');

// create instance
var webpage = phantom.create([`--proxy=proxy-nl.privateinternetaccess.com:1080`, `--proxy-type=socks5`, `--proxy-auth=***:***`]);

// open page
webpage.open('https://whatismyipaddress.com');
```

compiling with slimerjs

> ./node_modules/.bin/slimerjs app.js

The page opens, however it appears that my proxy is not being used, since the page shows my own IP.

I've tried a couple different proxies as well, nothing works, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Hey, KBS18, welcome to SO! How do you run your script? I'm a bit suspicious about those backticks in the phantom.create array, because PhantomJS wouldn't understand them, not sure about SlimerJS.

Comment: @Vaviloff I'm running this script by typing > ./node_modules/.bin/slimerjs app.js into the terminal.  I'll try removing the back ticks and see if that fixes the issue and report back here when I can do that.